# EV3 brick Bluetooth connection error

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software

I’m unable to pair the ev3 brick to our iPad mini. Both see each other but I keep getting this error on the ipad, Connection Unsuccessful, make sure ev3 is turned on and in range. And the ev3 shows a screen...[image]

WiFi I turned off on both and on the ev3 Bluetooth is turned on along with visibility. I’ve played around with checking and unchecking iPod/iPad/ etc box.

They paired before but we were experiencing inconsistencies with the brick while running programs and it was advised to try updating the brick so I did and now they are not pairing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing similar problem with my Windows PC and EV3 brick.

Restart bluetooth on both, PC/Mac and EV3.

Do NOT pair from the brick. 
Begin pairing from the EV3 Mindstorm App on your PC/Mac.

It should pair and work as expected.

Comment: This answer does not help. I upgraded and downgraded my firmware, tried, ipad toggle, restarted, it shows the wifi symbol but shows NONE in connections

Comment: I tried with Bluetooth. Haven't used wifi so can't comment

Comment: Pairing from the device helps. If you paired before, remove the bluetooth pairing.

Comment: Wireless connection on the EV3 is such garbage, this morning it took me over half an hour to pair the thing with both wi-fi and bluetooth to no avail. In fact, it was so hard that I received all sorts of error variations, to the point where the brick **CRASHED** when searching networks for the fifth time. I needed wireless because it was too hard to stick the big wire into the brick which was barricaded by other mechanisms, but after all the work I just wished I didn't do it in the first place. No, seriously, never use wireless. If the first try doesn't work then don't even bother fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this kind of problem a lot recently.

What helps me when I'm completely stuck: Re-Install the newest firmware (1.09H/E/D).

After this update restart the EV3, close all Apps (shut them down, not switching to Home) and try the connection again.

This helps me in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue - iPad and EV3 could see each other, but got the "Connection unsuccessful..." error message.

The EV3 and iPad had paired previously, and then I updated the EV3 firmware.  To resolve the issue, I went to the iPad's Settings->Bluetooth and found the EV3 brick listed.

I clicked on the information icon (blue i in a circle) and chose "Forget This Device".  I was able to then repair from inside the EV3 app.